# What does $\textstyle y \in \Re^{100}$ mean?

Tags: notation, real-numbers

Just reading online and came across this:

$\textstyle y \in \Re^{100}$

I am guessing it's something like "y is an element of [something about real numbers]".  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Perhaps you need to show more.  Maybe this is hundred-dimensional coordinate space?  Or maybe there is a footnote number 100?  Greater context may help determine whether it is one of these, or something else.

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: Definitely more context is needed. I've seen $R$ and $\textbf{R}$ to represent the set of all real numbers, but I have never seen $\mathfrak{R}$ used for this purpose (actually, I don't think I've seen that particular R period).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this means that $y$ is a $100^{th}$ dimensional real vector. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Vocabulary_and_notation)

> The notation $R^n$ refers to the cartesian product of $n$ copies of $R$, which is an $n$-dimensional vector space over the field of the real numbers; this vector space may be identified to the $n$-dimensional space of Euclidean geometry as soon as a coordinate system has been chosen in the latter. For example, a value from $R^3$ consists of three real numbers and specifies the coordinates of a point in $3$‑dimensional space.

Comment: I believe that usually, $\Re$ and $\Im$ are used to distinguish between the real and imaginary parts of a complex number.

Comment: @AndresMejia True, but in that case the meaning would be pretty specific to the context of the paper. I've never seen this notation otherwise. I'll inquire the OP about this

Comment: Nobody calls that a "100th dimensional real number." We call it a "!00th dimensional real vector."

Answer (score 3):

This may or may not be what Brevan Ellefsen has in mind, but if we say, for instance, that $y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, we often mean that $y$ is an ordered pair of real values: that is, $\{(p, q) \mid p, q \in \mathbb{R}\}$.  Thus, $(1, 4), (\pi, \sqrt{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, but $(i, 5), (\text{Bert}, \text{Ernie}) \not\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

In that light, we might guess (depending on context) that $\mathbb{R}^{100}$ is the set of all ordered tuples of real values containing $100$ elements.  But without more context, it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I was going for. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

In set theory, we write $X^Y$ to denote the set of all functions from $Y$ to $X$. This makes sense with the notations you know, for instance $\mathbb R^2$ is the set of functions from $\{1,2\} \to \mathbb R$ ; we usually denote such a function by its values, that is, $(x_1,x_2)$ (the function would be $x : \{1,2\} \to \mathbb R$ and $x(1) = x_1$, $x(2) = x_2$). I think the only unconventional thing about your question is the choice of calligraphy for the set of real numbers ; unless it's really some set described in your book, the real numbers are usually typed with *mathbb* so that it comes out like this $\mathbb R$. So $y \in \mathbb R^{100}$ just means a vector of real numbers with a hundred coordinates.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 2):

It is just "[Fraktur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur)", a German typeface, emphasizing of $R$, thus $\mathfrak{R}$, instead of the usual "[blackboard bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold)" emphasizing $\mathbb{R}$ or plain bold $\bf{R}$

A frequent use of $R$ for a set is the set of real numbers.

And the given expression is likely to be the Cartesian product of the set $R$, thus $100$-tuples with components from $R$.